# match phone numbers from text

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I have regex in php that matches pretty good phone numbers from some text.

```
([\+|0](?:[0-9/\-\(\) ] ?){7,25}[0-9])
```

good matches: `041 797 - 991` or `+386 2 80 55 291` or `+386 (0)41 718 827`

bad match: `000/000/13` (if it has three zeros in front doesn`t match, maybe?)

How could i remove this bad match?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [negative assertion  `(?!...)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that.

A similar example was also somewhere in the numberous existing questions on [php regex match phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20regex%20match%20phone%20numbers%20), just browse around.

Or you could just loop over the match results and filter them by your new criteria.

Comment: i tried it but couldn`t make it work on my example. maybe you know how to append this to my regex?

Comment: so it should go something like this: (?!000)([\+|0](?:[0-9/\-\(\) ] ?){7,25}[0-9]). im really not familiar with regex. thx

Comment: That looks alright and should give you the desired effect. Note that `[\+|0]` should just be `[+0]` and might interfer with the assertion still.

Comment: hmm but wont this wipe out 00 387... ? i would like to remove it if it contains three 000s. thx.

Comment: You could have told about those earlier. Then add a `\b` anchor the number matches, so the assertion sees them all.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply loop through for all of the numbers and then validate that (remove all extraneous characters):

```
preg_match_all("/\d/",$phone_number,$array);
// $array[0] will be an array of each digit
```

Then you can validate based on the length (e.g. decide if it has a country code or not and check it against a stored array or table).

Comment: thx, that was on my mind, but i want to know if it is possible to make if/loop inside regex.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your regex:

```
(?!(?:0[ /-]*){2,})([\+|0](?:[0-9/\-\(\) ] ?){7,25}[0-9])
```

Since you have already worked on your expression to allow certain characters that you see in your dataset, instead of writing a new one from scratch, I worked with yours.

The added phrase at the beginning is a negative lookahead.

```
(?!(?:0[ /-]*){2,})
```

Translation: Looking ahead at the beginning of the match, we don't want to see a { zero (optionally followed by characters such as a space, slash or hyphen)} two or more times.

If two zeros are actually okay, change the 2 to a three. Also tweak the characters inside [ /-] depending on what your data looks like.

I checked the regex against your sample data. It works.